# Sorting numbers in text file android

Tags: java, android, file

I am trying to sort the numbers in text file using android. Can you help me? This code is sorting part part not all of them. I mean it sorts 1.A 2.C 20.D 3.C 4.A 5.A like that. It should be 1.A 2.C 3.C 4.A 5.A 6.B 20.D I need to convert integer but how can I do that?

try
            {

```
           File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
            if (!root.exists()) 
            {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            File gpxfile = new File(root, fileName);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile,true);
            writer.append(s+"\n\n");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(gpxfile);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String inputLine;
            List<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
            while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                lineList.add(inputLine);
            }
            fileReader.close();
            Collections.sort(lineList);
            System.out.println(lineList);
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
            for (String outputLine : lineList) {
                out.println(outputLine);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            fileWriter.close();
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Data has been written to Report File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: where you sorting the numbers ?

Comment: @Mohit in text file I should sort. Collections.sort I used it but it sorts as a string therefore 1. 2. 20. 3... not 1. 2. 3. 20 but how can I do that?

Comment: try using `Set` instead

Comment: @Mohit I dont understand what you mean

Comment: You have to split the string and save it in a Integer array and then sort it .

Comment: @ Zahidul Islam How can I do that can you give me an example?

Comment: i mean use `Set<String>` instead of `List<String>`

Answer (score 3):

You are currently sorting `String` and you need to sort `Interger`

1. **Parsing "1.A 20.A 30.A 2.B 20.C 3.A"**

As it seems that your input file contains a mix of letter an numbers like **"1.A 20.A 30.A 2.B 20.C 3.A"** you can create en new class implementing `Comparable` to define your own sort.

```
class Item implements Comparable<Item>{
    String stringPart;
    Integer intPart;
    String c;

    public Item(String c){
        this.c = c;
        String[] res = c.split("\\.");
        intPart = Integer.valueOf(res[0]);
        stringPart = res[1];
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item o) {
        if(intPart.intValue() == o.intPart.intValue()){
            return stringPart.compareTo(o.stringPart);
        }else{
            return intPart.compareTo(o.intPart);
        }
    }

    public String getContent(){
        return c;
    }
}
```

Once done you can change the list definiton according to the new created class :

```
List<Item> lineList = new ArrayList<>();
```

The you can parse the input line to fill the list

```
List<Item> lineList = new ArrayList<>();
while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] res = inputLine.split(" ");
    for(String s : res){
        lineList.add(new Item(s));
    }
}
```

Sort the list content calling :

```
Collections.sort(lineList);
```

Write your output file :

```
for (Item i : lineList) {
    out.println(i.getContent());
}
```

The input

> "1.A 20.A 30.A 2.B 20.C 3.A"

Will produce

> 1.A
>   2.B
>   3.A
>   20.A
>   20.C
>   30.A

2. **Parsing "A.1 A.20 A.30 B.2 C.20 A.30"**

In case of having an input content switching character and number like this **"A.1 A.20 A.30 B.2 C.20 A.30"** you just have to modify the following to sort first on the characters and then on the numbers:

The reading of the content of the `Item`

```
intPart = Integer.valueOf(res[1]);
stringPart = res[0];
```

And the sorting method :

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Item o) {
    if(stringPart.equals(o.stringPart)){
        return intPart.compareTo(o.intPart);
    }else{
        return stringPart.compareTo(o.stringPart);
    }
}
```

Comment: this part should be string when I write yours it give an error while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                lineList.add(inputLine);
            }

Comment: `lineList.add(Integer.parseInt(inputLine));`

Comment: @ aioobe It closes the application

Comment: Check my update to sort a mix of characters and number like `1.A 20.A 30.A 2.B 20.C 3.A`

Comment: @Guillaume it closes apllication and same error NumberFormatException and Integer,invalidInt, Integer.parse, Integer.parseInt, Integer.valueOf

Comment: @Guillaume inputFie content is : 4.D 20.A ... etc

Answer (score 0):

As remarked above you are currently sorting strings. So the part

```
        List<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            lineList.add(inputLine);

        }
        fileReader.close();
        Collections.sort(lineList);
```

Has to be changed in something like:

```
        Map<Integer, String> list = new TreeMap<>();
        while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Read string is: " + inputLine);
            String[] entries= inputLine.split("\\s+");
            for(String entry: entries) {
                String values[] entry.split(".");
                if (values.size == 2) {
                   // Convert first part in integer      
                   if (values[0]!=null && !values[0].isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Converting string " + value[0] + " to integer");
                    list.put(Integer.valueOf(value[0]), value[1]);
                }
            }
        }
        fileReader.close();

        Stream<Map.Entry<K,V>> sorted =
                list.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(list.Entry.comparingByValue());
```

*NOTE:* Haven't tried the code above myself so there might be problems with it but it should (hopefully) clarify what needs to be done. I'm also not entirely sure whether strings like `2.` are properly converted.

Comment: It closes application. I think my problem is split method. My output 1.A 2.B  20.C 3.A in text file. inputLine.split(".") tried again it closes application. What should I write

Comment: Is there an exception shown? Possibly the read input line doesn't contain any characters.. Could you add `System.out.println("Read: " + inputLine);` within the loop.

Comment: The string `418a7f40` doesn't look like the example input you gave, (`1. 2. 20. 3. 4. 5.`). Are you sure that you reading the right file and that it contains the numbers as you have shown?

Comment: Read:          Read:4.D shows my output and below of 4.D it put just Read:

Comment: Added check whether number is not null or empty around `integer.valueof` statement (see above). Please retry

Comment: It again closes application. It gives error: NumberFormatException and Integer,invalidInt, Integer.parse, Integer.parseInt, Integer.valueOf

Comment: Added extra log statements in code above. Please retry and let me know what the output is

Comment: Converting string 4.D to integer. When I comment   numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(number)); this part. When I dont put on   numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(number)); it closes apllication and same error NumberFormatException and Integer,invalidInt, Integer.parse, Integer.parseInt, Integer.valueOf

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the input string. I thought it was `1. 2. 5. 20. 6.` but apparently it's '1.A 2.B 5.C etc`. This means that after splitting the string into tokens by spaces... we also have to do a split of the entry by . I have attempted to do this in the code above.

Comment: Yes it should be '1.A 2.B 5.C etc`.

Comment: The code does not give an error but does not sort it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110972/discussion-between-uniknow-and-xiac).